Django as_field_group?
How can I modify the as_field_group method to change the order of its returned values?
Currently, the method returns the label, error message, and then the input field. However, I want to customize it so that it returns the label first, then the input field, and finally the error message at the end.
How can I either override or customize the as_field_group method to achieve this?

You can add customized templates to the field as template_name attributes.
from django import forms

from .models import Stock

class StockForm(forms.ModelForm):
  
  price = forms.IntegerField(template_name="stock/custom_field.html", label="Stock-Price")
  
  class Meta:
    model = Stock
    fields = ('name', 'price')

As shown above, the price field of the Stock model will use custom_field.html.
The default value for template_name is forms/templates/field.html provided by django.
In other words, for StockForm models, custom_field.html is applied to the Price field and the field.html template provided by Django is applied to the Name field.
stock_edit.html
{% extends 'stock/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>New Stock</h1>
    <form method="POST" class="stock-form">{% csrf_token %}
      <div class="fieldWrapper">
        {{ form.name.as_field_group }}
      </div>
      <div class="fieldWrapper">
        {{ form.price.as_field_group }}
      </div>
        <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Save</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}

custom_field.html
{% if field.use_fieldset %}
  <fieldset{% if field.help_text and field.auto_id and "aria-describedby" not in field.field.widget.attrs %} aria-describedby="{{ field.auto_id }}_helptext"{% endif %}>
  {% if field.label %}{{ field.legend_tag }}{% endif %}
{% else %}
  {{ field }}{% if field.use_fieldset %}</fieldset>{% endif %}
  {% if field.label %}{{ field.label_tag }}{% endif %}
{% endif %}
{{ field.errors }}

My custom_html template had the input part ahead of the label for testing.

Looking at the above picture, you can check that the custom_field.html is applied to the price field.
My test was for the single field.
If you would like to work on all fields, please refer to this article.
